# Java send email, Getting error

Tags: java

I wrote a program to send emails, but I don't know why I am getting an error.

Pleas help me.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class EmailTest {

    static Properties mailServerProperties;
    static Session getMailSession;
    static MimeMessage generateMailMessage;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        generateAndSendEmail();
        System.out.println("\n\n ===> Your Java Program has just sent an Email successfully. Check your email..");
    }

    public static void generateAndSendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {


        System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
        mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtpout.secureserver.net");
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");


        System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
        getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
        generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to@to.com"));
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("cc@cc.com"));
        generateMailMessage.setSubject("TEST");
        String emailBody = "TEST BODY" + "<br><br> DFKSDL, <br>JDSKJFDS";
        generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
        System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");


        System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
        Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        // Enter your correct gmail UserID and Password
        transport.connect("smtpout.secureserver.net", "username@user.com", "password");
        transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error.  The username and password and everything are correct, but I am getting this error:

```
 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..
Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..


 2nd ===> get Mail Session..
Mail Session has been created successfully..


 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 <username@partik-pc> Sender Rejected - MAIL FROM must be a valid domain.
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 <username@partik-pc> Sender Rejected - MAIL FROM must be a valid domain.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at EmailTest.generateAndSendEmail(EmailTest.java:50)
    at EmailTest.main(EmailTest.java:20)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 <username@partik-pc> Sender Rejected - MAIL FROM must be a valid domain.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1616)
    ... 3 more
```

I don't know why, username@partik-pc it puts my PC name after the username!! I don't know why.  Also, how can I attach a file? Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it!! can you please explain me again!!

Comment: I write email with domain as well!!:(

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `mail.from` property with a valid email address that is accepted by your mail server:

```
mailServerProperties.put("mail.from", "your@emailaddress.com");
```

Or you need to explicitly set the from address:

```
generateMailMessage.setFrom("me@example.com");
```

See also the example on the [api of JavaMail](http://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/)

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with this problem all morning. Oddly enough I used to send emails from a Gmail account and didn't get this error. But today I switched to my godaddy domain email and had this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
    public void sendMessageToUser(){

    String msgTitle = "Title";
    String msgBody = "msgBody";
    String userEmail = "user@gmail.com";
    final String username = "username";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.your.post");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "your port");

   Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator(){
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
   });

   try{
       Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("FROM ME"));
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(userEmail));
       message.setSubject(msgTitle);
       message.setText(msgBody);

       Transport.send(message);

   } catch (MessagingException ex){
       //Error
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried it!!, I didn't get any error but it didn;t send email as well!! Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: @user2704140   you change properties in my code example? This `prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.your.post");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "your port");` need to change:)

Comment: prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "your port"); what about this line??your port??

Comment: Change  `prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.your.post")`   to  `prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtpout.secureserver.net")`  

and delete  `prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "your port")`  if you no care about specific port.

And, of course - use your resl username and password.

Comment: I removed that line, already!! but, still same!! in my code variable username and password unused!!

Comment: getting error,  Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator(){
         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
             return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
         }
    });

Comment: Use your real username and password.
In your code you use this:

`transport.connect("smtpout.secureserver.net", "username@user.com", "password");`

in my code, I use this structure:

`   Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator(){
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
   });`

There I put my username and password from my mail service.

Comment: I am trying, run the program but, error,                            The method getInstance(Properties, Authenticator) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (Properties, new Authenticator(){})                                                                      The constructor PasswordAuthentication(String, String) is undefined   Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator(){
         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
             return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
         }
    });

Comment: Strange... You have all this imports - `import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;` ??

Comment: I have import but Javax.mail ---> The import javax.mail cannot be resolved  Please help me thanks!!

Comment: How that happen? You alredy have javax.mail in you code on startpost. Well then, you have Java Mail API in your classpath. I am right?

Comment: Can you public your full code somewhere (on GitHub, for example) and put link on comments there? And I try to help with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setFrom` method to set the sender as well.

Comment: I need to add "addRecipient(Message.RecipientType rt, String arg1);     " ?? sorry, I am completely lost!!:( Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: No, you need to set the `FROM` address using the `setFrom` method. If you don't, Java uses your user name and domain by default. That's why you see `username@partik-pc` as the `FROM` address. You don't seem to be in a domain, so the domain name is your machine name.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message : Sender Rejected - **MAIL FROM** must be a valid domain.

Try to set the From field: [MimeMessage.setFrom(Address ...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setFrom%28javax.mail.Address%29)

Answer (score 0):

You should include "from" part:

```
generateMailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));
```

Just below `generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);`

Comment: I know, Actually I put my office email address!!I changed it in question!!Please help me thansk!!

Comment: Yes :) but you should adopt it into your codes.Of course you wont use msg variable for example.

Comment: I add this line!! still getting error, where i need to add this lines?? I think I add this line at different place!!Please help me!! Thansk!!:)